# Click counts on specific referral links

Tags: php, mysql

Hello Dear Stackoverflow users i am experiencing with one problem hope you guys will help me to solve this.
I am trying to save hits on referral links to database and show on user admin panel..
I found many question but nothing helped me..!

Example: http://example.com/ref=546215

Is it possible to count clicks on referral link?

 i am using php on my script..

This is what i tried:

```html
<?php 
include("connect.php");
if (isset($_GET['ref'])) {
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO hit ('-ref-','data')");
}
?>
```

Comment: Please check the mysql query result and then post if any error displayed.

Comment: Can you please provide me that query?

Comment: Is that a typo in the example URL? There's no `?`.

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO hit ('-ref-','data')"); what is the result of this query.

Comment: @siddhesh It is not working not inserting data to database..

Comment: will you please show database table used for storing the clicks information

Comment: @siddhesh i just created emply table with two rows ref and data

Comment: what will be the data variable do

Comment: @siddhesh it will save how many hits to refferal link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to give you the database schema and the query for inserting it from what i understand from your question.
i am providing you the concept and the queries i hope that you can convert it into php program

Table Hit

ref | no_of_hits

```
create table hit(

ref varchar(255) UNIQUE KEY,

no_of_hits int(11)
);

//first check here if ref is available
 select * from hit where ref =[ref]
// if not available then insert ref with no_of hit 1
insert into Hit (ref,no_of_hits)  values([ref],1) 
//if available then increase the no_of_hits by 1
UPDATE hit SET no_of_hits = no_of_hits + 1 WHERE ref = [ref];
```

Any doubts?